# How to know copying of files in progress in to directory - java

Tags: java

We have a directory for which we have file listeners . As soon as the file is placed in directory some application level logic will trigger.
But while copying big files as well this process is triggered.how to make sure that files are copied to the directory

Comment: Haven't tried, but you could place a requirement that there be a small time limit between updates for any given file...

Comment: Do you mean you want to make sure the file has finished before you do anything?